# Hybris - Trigger update process by command line

Tags: bash, command-line, continuous-integration, sap-commerce-cloud

With Hybris you need to do an 'update running system', when updating platform code and certain data / *.xml files has changed.

This is a manual process and for that it doesn't really fit into a CI environment.

There are 2 options, initialise or update. But both look like it can't be triggered from the command line / bash

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29981777/2750476

I wonder if anyone knows the command line for triggering the update process (for updating the type system definitions)

Or did anyone found another solution for continuously updating a hybris platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ant target 'updatesystem' :

> **updatesystem** Runs an update system of the
>   specified tenant in stand-alone mode, using hybris Administration
>   Console default settings or the configuration from a given file.
>   Syntax: ant updatesystem [-Dtenant=tenantID -DdryRun=true|false
>   -DtypeSystemOnly=true|false -DconfigFile=PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE]

Comment: the process doesn't quit with an exit code, so for continues integration it becomes a bit hard to include.. Do you maybe know if its runnable, and that it exits after its done?? Thanks again :)

Comment: It exits with and exit code for me, what version of Hybris are you using ? If you confortable with it you could customize the ant target.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command from your command prompt

```
ant updatesystem -Dtenant=master -DdryRun=false -DtypeSystemOnly=true
```